# Sending color to Arduino through serial using Objective-c

Tags: c++, serial-port, arduino, iokit

I am trying to send color to Arduino through serial. This is the Objective-C code running on my mac, which sends the color to the Arduino:

```
unsigned char rgb[4];
rgb[1] = ...some color
rgb[2] = ...some color
rgb[3] = ...some color
rgb[0]=0xff; //I am setting the first value to 0xff so I know where to start reading the bytes
if(_serialFileDescriptor!=-1) {
    write(_serialFileDescriptor, rgb, 4);
}
```

After I send it Arduino receives it. I first check if the first byte it read is 0xff to synchronise Arduino with computer. If it is i go on and get colors. Now the problem is that apparently the first byte is never 0xff and the if statement never gets entered.

```
    void loop(){
         //protocol expects data in format of 4 bytes
         //(xff) as a marker to ensure proper synchronization always
         //followed by red, green, blue bytes
         char buffer[4];
         if (Serial.available()>3) {
          Serial.readBytes(buffer, 4);
          if(buffer[0] == 0xff){ //when I comment out the if statement code works fine but    //the colors which are read are wrong
           red = buffer[1];
           green= buffer[2];
           blue = buffer[3];
          }
         }
         //finally control led brightness through pulse-width modulation
         analogWrite (redPin, red);
         analogWrite (greenPin, green);
         analogWrite (bluePin, blue);
        }
```

I don't get why the first read byte is bever 0xff even though is set it to this in the Objective-C code.

Comment: There seems to be some mixup between `rgb` and `rgba` in your code.

Comment: If the first byte is *not* 0xFF then you probably should read only one byte and not 4 bytes (or remember/shift the remaining bytes in the buffer).

Comment: I had a bit of mess up in my code, I am sorry. I corrected it though. I actually was intending to not read the bytes at all if the first byte is not 0xff.

Comment: As an aside, it's very challenging to use actual Objective-C on an Arduino, and your code is entirely C++/C at most.  Re-tagging.

Answer (score 0):

what I would do is:

1. from the computer, send a header byte to the Arduino to know that
   useful information is coming next.
2. from the computer send the number
   of data packets that are coming next
3. on the Arduino, loop through
   the number of data with each time a serial read to `buffer[i]`.

so the code would look like that (might need improvement):

```
uint8_t dataHeader = 0xff;
uint8_t numberOfData;
uint8_t rgb[3];
uint8_t redPin, greenPin, bluePin;

void setup(){

    Serial.begin(9600);

    // INITIALIZE YOUR PINS AS YOU NEED
    //
    //


}

void loop(){

    if (Serial.available() > 1) {

        uint8_t recievedByte = Serial.read();

        if (recievedByte  == dataHeader) { // read first byte and check if it is the beginning of the stream

            delay(10);
            numberOfData = Serial.read(); // get the number of data to be received.

            for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfData ; i++) {
                delay(10);
                rgb[i] = Serial.read();
            }

        }

    }

    analogWrite (redPin, rgb[0]);
    analogWrite (greenPin, rgb[1]);
    analogWrite (bluePin, rgb[2]);

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well, the length of data is always supposed to be 3, so I don't think there is need to send the length. I tried both using the serial.readbytes() and serial.read() both did not work, and I feel for same reason. However I am a bit concerned about the header byte, because in my code although I do send the header byte, I when I add the IF statement to check for header byte, the code never enters the IF statement. Is the header byte supposed to be an int or a char?

Comment: For your strict case, the number of data is indeed not required. BUT, you might want to improve your code later, add motors, add more leds with different colors. With this code, you'll be able to add more cases with less rewriting.
As for the `dataHeader` and `if` statement, try my edit.
One question though: how do you send those bytes from the computer?

Comment: In the Arduino language, a `char` is used to store a character value.
`Serial.read()` reads the first `byte`, 8 bits, so you need to store it as a `byte` type. Sometime, Arduino data types differ from basic C/C++ data types, so I prefer using int8_t or uint8_t and so on to know exactly how many bits I need and if it is signed or unsigned.

Comment: I actually think I should change the dataheader to something different, because 0xff could be a color. The way it think I should be sending bytes from computer is as I shown in my post. However I probably should change it to something like rgb[0] = 'header'; I am not sure though if I should be sending the bytes with a single array with a single write() or a multiple write()s

Comment: Here is a more complete example to demonstrate the usefulness of `numberOfData` : https://github.com/WeAreLeka/moti/blob/moti_v2/lib/Moti/Moti_Remote.cpp
I spotted some mistakes that I'll correct latter, but you get the idea.

Comment: Yes it could be a color, but every byte could be a color. A byte = 8 bits = from 0 to 255 (0x00 to 0xFF in Hex). If you send an uint16_t, it's 2 bytes, 16 bits but you'll have the same problem because `Serial.read()` gets the first byte (8bits) of the serial buffer.
On the computer side, you can use the same technique: dataHeader, numberOfData (if you plan on adding new actions), actual data.